# iOS: SQLite Insert Query not working

Tags: ios, sqlite, fmdb

Im trying to insert some values to my sqlite database. The db is already of the doc folder on the phone. I cant figure out what is going wrong. I set trace executing but the db tells me that it does not have any error. Can someone help me?

```
if([[TRSharedLocalDatabase openDatabase] executeUpdateWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO event (title,date,address,latitude,longitude,location,facebookID,picPath,description) VALUES (%@,%@,%@,%@,%@,%@,%@,%@,%@)",event.title ,event.date, event.address, [NSNumber numberWithDouble:event.geoPoint.longitude], [NSNumber numberWithDouble:event.geoPoint.latitude], event.location.objectId, event.facebookID ,picPath ,event.description]) {    
    NSLog(@"Ok");  
} else {  
    NSLog(@"Not Ok");  
}  

+(FMDatabase *)openDatabase {  
     NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];  
    NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"4PartyLocalSystem.sqlite"];  
    **FMDatabase *database = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:writableDBPath];**  
    [database open];  
    [database setTraceExecution:YES];  
    return database;   
}
```

> 2013-08-06 13:21:42.499 4Party[13018:907]  executeUpdate: INSERT INTO event (title,date,address,latitude,longitude,location,facebookID,picPath,description) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,**@**,?,?,?)

Comment: Rafael, it would be helpful if you provided more information about the  `TRSharedLocalDatabase`. Can you share the code for the method `openDatabase`? It will be difficult to help you without knowing more about what that code is doing, exactly.

Comment: The openDatabase method is just for opening the DB. Here it is:NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"4PartyLocalSystem.sqlite"];
    FMDatabase *database = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:writableDBPath];
    [database open];
    [database setTraceExecution:YES];
    return database;

Comment: Please add the code to the question by editing it rather than add it in a comment. It is virtually impossible to read your code in the comment

Comment: Thanks, can you put that in the original post? Also add the code for the `databaseWithPath:`. You will also want to consider adding some error handling to your code on the SQLite operations. That will give you more information about specific errors.

Comment: I tried logging the sql errors, but the db always return me "not an error". @Aaron

Comment: Show the code that is logging the errors, which might mean posting the code from `FMDatabase databaseWithPath:`. There is alot of documentation on SQLite result codes: http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_abort.html

Comment: I see. FMDatabase looks like a wrapper around SQLite. I didn't realize that. https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb. After `databaseWithPath:` completes, is `database` not null? Meaning was it created successfully? If so, then your problem is with the `executeUpdateWithFormat` method call.

Comment: There is no error. Thats really strange. Im sure that the db is open, I think it is a query error. @Aaron

Comment: Have you verified that `database` is not nil? In obj-c you can send messages to nil pointers. Verify this by debugging to the line `[database open];`.

Comment: I added if ([TRSharedLocalDatabase openDatabase]open]) { NSLog(@"Correct") }. And it returned me "correct". Look the line I added to the post. It seems that the error is the '@'. @Aaron

Comment: You say you looked at the error. But if you're not saving the `FMDatabase` pointer in some variable (like below), I'm not sure you'd do that. You should open the database once, do all of your interaction with that object and close it when you're done.

Comment: If you're going to use the `%@` format in your SQL statement (which I don't advise), you have to quote those (e.g. `@"INSERT INTO event (title, date, address, latitude, longitude, location ,facebookID ,picPath ,description) VALUES ('%@', '%@', '%@', '%@', '%@', '%@', '%@', '%@', '%@')"`). Much better to use `?` placeholders with `executeUpdate` for myriad reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two observations:

1. You should examine the `lastErrorMessage` of the database if you have an error. It helps if you store the database pointer in a separate variable if you're going to do multiple calls to the database before closing it.

   You definitely don't want to call `[TRSharedLocalDatabase openDatabase]` multiple times for one session with your database. Or you could refactor it to conform to a singleton pattern.
2. Ideally, you should use `?` placeholders in your SQL with [`executeUpdate`](http://ccgus.github.io/fmdb/html/Classes/FMDatabase.html#//api/name/executeUpdate:) method, not printf-style placeholders with `executeUpdateWithFormat` (see the warning in the [executeUpdateWithFormat documentation](http://ccgus.github.io/fmdb/html/Classes/FMDatabase.html#//api/name/executeUpdateWithFormat:)). If not, your text fields with characters that need to be escaped (e.g. quotation mark) won't be. (This also protects you against SQL injection attacks.)

Thus:

```
FMDatabase *database = [TRSharedLocalDatabase openDatabase];
if (!database) {
    NSLog(@"Unable to open database");
    return;
}

if([database executeUpdate:@"INSERT INTO event (title,date,address,latitude,longitude,location,facebookID,picPath,description) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",event.title ,event.date, event.address, [NSNumber numberWithDouble:event.geoPoint.longitude], [NSNumber numberWithDouble:event.geoPoint.latitude], event.location.objectId, event.facebookID ,picPath ,event.description]) {    
    NSLog(@"Ok");  
} else {  
    NSLog(@"Not Ok: %@", [database lastErrorMessage]);  
}  

[database close];
```

Comment: THANKSSS!!! I stored the FMDatabase in a variable and then the DB could log the lastErrorMessage!! Now i fixed the query!!